# Why Was Severus So Rude To Almost Everyone?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape

I understand why Severus is rude to Harry, but why to everyone else?

Snape is rude to Harry, over a grudge between him and James Potter, but he is also bitter to many Gryffindor students as well. This sentence from Wood, the Gryffindor Quidditch player backs up this question.

> It's not my fault, we've just got to make sure we play a clean game, so **Snape hasn't got an excuse to pick on us.**

Why is Severus rude to almost everyone else?

Comment: Like many people who were bullied as kids, I think Snape just grew up hurt and angry and found himself in a position of power that he relished being able to wield.

Comment: I agree with Phantom42 on this one

Comment: I feel this question is opinion-based.

Comment: *Almost everybody*? Who was he not rude to?

Comment: @KharoBangdo He wasn't rude to Albus Dumbledore.

Comment: @Slytherincess - Et tu, Brutus? It's Good Subjective, even so.

Comment: @KharoBangdo Malfoy, or probably anyone else from Slytherin.

Comment: I genuinely do not understand why this question is opinion based. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple reasons for this, all cumulative.

1. Snape's innate personality and psyche. While not an expert, I would be not surprised if he's on [low end of the spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asperger_syndrome) based on several symptoms, like many brilliant geeks are. As such, he has VERY little ability for interpersonal relationships and extremely low [Emotional Intelligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_intelligence).
2. Snape is brilliant. As many such people (especially reinforced with #1), he has very low patience with anyone less than brilliant who he isn't forced to respect. That isn't exactly a very good trait in a **school** teacher - he'd be better off teaching grad students; and thus results in him being irritated at having to stoop to dealing with what he perceives as endless stupidity and mediocrity.

   This is something common in Potterverse - witness how Hermione Granger comes across, especially at the start of the First Year (and to be honest, most of the time as well) - and her EI quotient is pretty high, comparatively.

   Note that this trait by Snape is slightly masked, because he's equally rude to Hermione Granger (and I don't recall him abusing Crabbe and Goyle) ... but that's explainable easily by #5 and #6.
3. Snape grew up in an abusive home. Research shows that this generally leaves people predisposed to abuse and to bad personality.
4. Snape almost certainly suffers from PTSD, from the end of First War as well as serving as a spy in an extremely dangerous circumstances.
5. He has unresolved issues from his time at Hogwarts (rivalry with James/Marauders, losing Lily's love), which is exacerbated by "Stupid Gryffindor bravery" leading to Lily's death.

   So he generally hates all things Gryffindor, even above his baseline personality.

   This explains the fact that he's even rude to Hermione who otherwise should have been his teacher's pet due to high IQ like she is to other teachers; or Wood's Quidditch concerns quoted in OP's question.
6. Last, but not least, he has a specific image to maintain, to ensure his success as a spy. He **must** be seen as uber-Slytherin, hateful to other houses - especially Gryffindor - and "evil".

   Being a caustic jerk is quite helpful to that end; so he would likely have cultivated that approach even if all the above-mentioned points didn't make it natural.

Answer (score 3):

Severus Snape had a very rough life. His parents fought often, as his mother was a witch, his father a muggle, and in retrospect Tom Riddle was pretty much the same. Severus revealed the magical world to Lily and loved her since the day first met, then she goes on to marry his nemesis James Potter. Imagine this, you childhood love refuses to have anything to do with you believing your choice of friends was evil and marries the person you hate most. The person who curses you, hangs you upside down and takes off your pants. To make it worse, with Lily watching. Any person in his situation would of gone twisted and evil inside. But not Snape, although he seems evil and rude he actually saves Harry from Quirrell. I believe that seeing Harry is like rubbing salt in a old wound for Snape, the face of a rival with the eyes of a old love.

Answer (score 0):

He's a Meyers-Briggs INTJ — a person with little regard for the empty words and empty gestures of ordinary existence.  Politeness, if it clouds the truth is a negative thing to most INTJs.

Reference: [Portrait of an INTJ - Introverted iNtuitive Thinking Judging](https://www.personalitypage.com/INTJ.html)

> INTJs spend a lot of time inside their own minds, and may have little interest in the other people's thoughts or feelings.
>
> ... may cause the INTJ to dismiss others input too quickly, and to become generally arrogant and elitist.
>
> Other people may have a difficult time understanding an INTJ.

Comment: Last time I checked we didn't have the MBTIs for Harry Potter characters. This seems like a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @Hydrothermal - nothing formal, but he certainly fits. He was almost certainly on the spectrum, too (I might ask when I feel like enduring the downvotes)

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77056/do-we-have-enough-information-to-determine-severus-snapes-meyers-briggs-type

Comment: @ hydrothermal:  We don't have types for most characters, but INTJs tend to stand out obviously.