# Do we have enough information to determine Severus Snape's Meyers-Briggs type?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape, psychology

One of recent SFF.SE answers alleged that Snape is an INTJ, and there was a disagreement of whether we can really know that.

Do we have enough information to determine Severus Snape's Meyers-Briggs type? If so, what is it likely to be?

*P.S. I'm aware that not everyone neatly fits into a single M-B type, myself included, so an answer that legitimately says "part X and part Y" is quite acceptable*.

The reasoning **must** be fully based on canon info (books/Pottermore/WoG) and standard M-B guidelines.

Comment: Do people voting to close even understand what "opinion" based means? M-B offers very specific guidelines on typing individuals, which can be confirmed by information from canon. It may not be *trivial* to answer (there's a reason M-B has so many questions in it) but it's pretty non-opinion-based at its core.

Comment: Also please note that the question asks if we have enough information to determine the type, _not_ what his type _is_. The answer is, most likely, "no", but I think you'd have to have a degree in psychology _and_ in depth knowledge of the _Harry Potter_ franchise to answer this properly.

Comment: @SQB - "There's a small pool of experts who can answer this" != "opinion based".

Comment: Yes, I'm actually agreeing with that. I'm sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: M-B may offer very specific guidelines on typing individuals, but it's unclear if those typings actually *mean* anything. There's quite a bit of evidence that not only does "not everyone" fit neatly into types, *most* people don't, which sort of goes against the whole idea of "types" to begin with. On the other hand, it isn't conclusive that Meyers-Briggs types *aren't* meaningful, either.

Answer (score 2):

I know we did Hermione's MB type once, kind of as a spoof. That question was -- rightfully, in hindsight -- closed, and then -- wrongly, IMO -- reopened. MB is a licensed standardized test that is administered by professionals trained in MB. We, as laypeople, would probably just argue over what personality type Snape is. Snape is also a fictional character and pretty one-dimensional at that (Don't get your feathers ruffled! I ***love*** Snape as a character.). No, we cannot really expect to do an accurate MB on Snape, just as I feel we could never really diagnose Snape as a sociopath.

Armchair psychology is great fun, but it's not controlled. It's opinion-based. I'm voting to close this question as opinion-based accordingly.

<sub>I don't want to presume, but some may have noticed I have my MB results in my user profile. This is only because it's a genuine MB test result, not an internet test, and my profession is in psychology. Just wanted to put that out there before someone started hassling me about it ;))))</sub>

Comment: Downvote me if you want -- I can take the hit. But, no, sorry, we cannot diagnose fictional characters using real life psychological tools, no matter how fun that may be. Note: When the author of a given character says, "I based this character on a psychopath" or whatever, that is a whole 'nother issue.

Comment: do you seriously mean to suggest that it's hard to tell based on canon info that Snape is intriverted or extroverted? :)  Or thinking vs. feeling? One-dimensional or not, it's a fairly complete character.

Comment: Also, out of sheer curiosity, is there **any** evidence that the "licensed" test givers actually produce results in any way different from reputable online tests? Very frequently, in USA, "licensed" is more about either legal CYA, or about distorting competitive field by using the power of the state, as opposed to anything resembling ability. AFAIK, 100% of the reasoning behind the typing is publicly known and not some secret information only licensed givers own.